# Как разнести три div: влево, по центру и вправо с выравниванием блоков по вертикали

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: отцентрировав блоки по вертикали, попытался разнести их влево/по центру/вправо. При попытке сделать это через

```
float: right;
```

или

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

выравнивание внутренних блоков по вертикали слетает, и они прилипают к верху внешнего блока.

Как победить данную проблему, без использования transform?

```css
.main {
  background: grey;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main:before {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
}
.logo {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
.menu {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
.auth {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
        логотип
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        основное меню
    </div>
    <div class="auth">
        авторизация
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему не flex?

Comment: Не поддерживается IE8.

Comment: @Дмитрий Надо дополнить вопрос, если есть какие-то требования поддержака броузеров и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Мне так интересно взглянуть на комп, на котором установлен только IE-11 и ниже.....

Comment: @Kosta B. Нужна поддержка IE8 и выше, по этой причине отмел решение с использованием transform.

Answer (score 2):

**Все примеры приведённые в моём ответе работать будут даже в arachne**

Вот так, на **inline-block**

```css
.main {
  text-align: justify;
}

.main:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.main div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="logo">
    логотип
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    основное меню
  </div>
  <div class="auth">
    авторизация
  </div>
</div>
```

**на float + inline-block**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.logo,
.menu,
.auth {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}

.auth {
  float: right;
  background: blue;
}

.menu {
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="logo">
    логотип
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    основное меню
  </div>
  <div class="auth">
    авторизация
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**table + table-cell**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo,
.menu,
.auth {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.logo,
.auth {
  width: 30%;
}

.menu {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="logo">
    логотип
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    основное меню
  </div>
  <div class="auth">
    авторизация
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**position:absolute**

недостатки очевидны, этот метод хоть и работает но его лучше не применять

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
}

.logo,
.menu,
.auth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: white;
}

.logo {
  left: 0;
}

.auth {
  right: 0;
}

.menu {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="logo">
    логотип
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    основное меню
  </div>
  <div class="auth">
    авторизация
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В 1, 2 и 4 примерах дивы прибивает к верху.
А вот 3 пример наиболее близок к истине, но там дивы растягивает по высоте родительского блока и центрует их содержимое, а не сами дивы.

Comment: @Дмитрий  по другому ни как ни делать - если хотите велосипедить то удачи

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {text-align: justify; line-height: 0;}
.main:after {content:''; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 0;}
.logo, .menu, .auth {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: Пропало выравнивание внутренних блоков по вертикали.

Comment: Ну так не надо задавать высоту жёстко, есть паддинги. А если прям надо - оборачиваем всё это дело дополнительно в блоки с display:table, display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle